# looking for locations of a string in a given string

Tags: python, pycharm

The question is using python, find all numbers from a string (int and float) , sort the output in ascending order, and find their location in the string (start, length).

As an example, with an input of '123klja32.23alk543$^&d',
the output should be:
number_list = [32.23, 123, 543]
location_list = [[7, 5], [0, 3], [15, 18]]

I have successfully sorted out the numbers in ascending order.
I tried to find the starting location of the three numbers, but the output only indicates that the number does not exist in the input.
When trying, I used list.find() method to check the three numbers existing in the input. However, the output is -1, -1, -1, which they don't exist in the input. I also used other methods to find the location of the three, but error messages poped up.
Therefore, I hope you could explain me the problem and help to find the answer.
And though I sorted out ascending numbers, my output gives [[32.23], [123], [543]]. I would be very grateful if you could also help me print it as the example shown above, [32.23, 123, 543].

Here is the code I have written.

```
    # get input from a user
    #input = input()
    input = '123klja32.23alk543$^&d'

    # empty string and a list needed to save and to cast the numbers
    string = ''
    list_float = list()
    location = list()

    # find only the numbers: integer and float
    for c in input:
        if '0' <= c <= '9' or c == '.':
            string += c + ''
        else:
            string += ' '

    # split them and put in a list
    list = string.split((' '))

    # remove empty strings from a list of strings
    while '' in list:
        list.remove('')

    # cast the objects into float and integer by mapping
    for x in list:
        if '.' in x:
            list_float.append([float(x)])
        else:
            list_float.append([int(x)])

    # sort the list in ascending order
    list_float.sort()
    print(list_float) # print the sorted list

    # find their location list
    for x in list_float:
        print(input.find(str(x), 0, len(input)))  <-- this is where I get the error
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears your `list_float` is a list of *lists* of numbers, so `input.find(str(x)` will try to find substrings like `"[123]"`, which do not exist. Change that bit to `input.find(str(x[0])`, then it should work (or fix the bit where you create the sublists with `append([...])`).

However, your approach with `find` will still fail in case there are repeated numbers in the string, or numbers that are parts of other numbers.

Instead, you could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to find the numbers and their positions:

```
>>> import re                                                              
>>> s = "123klja32.23alk543$^&d"                                           
>>> p = r"-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?"                                                 
>>> sorted((float(m.group()), m.span()) for m in re.finditer(p, s))        
[(32.23, (7, 12)), (123.0, (0, 3)), (543.0, (15, 18))]
```

Comment: Thank you. what you explained about "[123]" really helped a lot:)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```py
import re                                                              


input_str = '123klja32.23alk543$^&d'
num_rex = r"\d+(?:\.\d*)?"
number_list = []
location_list = []
val_dict = {}

for val in re.finditer(num_rex, input_str):
    val_dict[eval(val.group())] = list(val.span())

val_dict = sorted(val_dict.items())

for val in val_dict:
    number_list.append(val[0])
    location_list.append(val[1])

print(f'number_list = {number_list}')
print(f'location_list = {location_list}')
```

**Output:**

```
number_list = [32.23, 123, 543]
location_list = [[7, 12], [0, 3], [15, 18]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not allowed to use libraries, you can let Python do the float conversion to check for valid float substrings using a try/except statement.  By asking forgiveness rather than permission from the automatic conversion, you eliminate all concerns of digits, decimal point and negative sign.

```
S = '123klja32.23alk543$^&d'
locations  = []                 # list of [position,size]
start,size = 0,0                # current subrange
for c in S:                     # loop once per character in S
    try:
        float(S[start:start+size+1+(c=='-')]) # attempt conversion
        if not size:                     # new float subrange
            locations.append([start,0])
        size += 1                        # extend size to attempt longer
        locations[-1][-1] = size         # update list of float subranges
    except:                              # failed float conversion
        start,size = start+size+1,0      # start new subrange
locations = sorted(locations,key=lambda loc:float(S[loc[0]:sum(loc)])) 
numbers   = [float(S[p:p+s]) for p,s in locations] 

print(numbers)    # [32.23, 123.0, 543.0]
print(locations)  # [[7, 5], [0, 3], [15, 3]]
```